# ajax returns response in error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a simple ajax script but it returns response in error and it should return as success. It doesnt fire success alert but shows propper response in error alert. In firebug console i see 200 ok and propper response. What could be the problem?

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/GetPhotos?categoryid=tohome',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Comment: looks like you have a invalid json in the response... can you share the response data...

Comment: What is `alert(error)` value in error callback?

Comment: your console should have an error saying a parse error

Comment: Thanks, i will test the response now

Comment: Thanks, it was invalid json in response.